# Scoring stop and reset the game on javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm basically a manual tester now trying to upskill in javascript. I'm developing a mini project
on javascript it's called the Hand cricket. It's nothing but my child hood game that I played with
my friends. So I have a function here which checks if the player is out or not. If the player
is out, I'm not able to stop the game, still user is able to provide inputs. Please help me how
should I stop the program once the player gets out. It should stop the game and reset the
player score after few seconds.
Below is the code snippet....

I have declared the Player score as

```
  ////// player score initialised to zero

  let pScore = 0;

  // checking if the player is out

  //comparing hands

    const compareHands = (playerChoice, computerChoice) => {
  //updating text
    const winner = document.querySelector(".winner");
    
  //checking player is out

    if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
        winner.textContent = "You are out!";    
        return;
    }
    else {
        updateScore(playerChoice);
    }
};
```

**Updating the score board:**

```
  const updateScore = (playerChoice) => {
    let playerScore = document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML;
    let scores = getScoreInDigits(playerChoice)
    playerScore = parseInt(playerScore) + scores.pScore;
    document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = playerScore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the button before **return**:

```
button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
```